# Change global.asax for owin startup to use signalR 2

Tags: asp.net, .net, signalr, owin

I have MVC 4 aplication. I want to upgrade signalR version to 2.x.x. When I tried to init signalR hubs, visual studio says that I have to move that init to Owin startup file. I don´t have experience with OWIN.

My question is, what does this change entail?

I have noticed that in OWIN startup I don´t have application events like in global.asax for example. I have read that startup doesn´t have session events like Session_End neither.

Comment: You could have owin startup and global asax in the same application. OWIN is a middleware that runs before asp.net application life cycle

Comment: Thanks, finally I do that and it seems that everything is ok